# Swift Animation - Circle behind button

Tags: swift, animation, button, swift3, geometry

I'm trying to add some animation in my app. I would like to show a circle when I tap a button.

[image]
[image]

I don't really know what could be the best way to do that.

Do I have to create on the storyboard a view with a background, and I add corner radius and use the `isHidden` property ?

Do I have to create the circle programmatically ? Maybe better because I have many buttons ?

Comment: have you heard of `UIButtonState`? you can set a circle image for a button's highlighted state. That would work for your case

Comment: Even if by button is already an image ??

Comment: you can set different background image for different states of the button. Don't get confused with the `image` & `backgroundImage`

Comment: I see ! But in that case I need different image circle if my buttons have different size. Moreover, I can't really "play" with the scale of the circle behind and the image right ?

Answer (score 3):

**BEST WAY:**

**DEMO**

[image]

**1. Assets Used**

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Set Default Image on `Default State` of `UIButton`

[image]

3. Set Highlighted Image on `Highlighted State` of `UIButton`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! But I'm really sorry, it's not exactly what I would like :/ .. I would like the same effet than pinterest: the icon has a litlle scale when we are touching the button, and the is a circle which is scaling up behind. (Sorry again for my english)

Comment: to scale the button when highlighted, you will have to scale it using `CGAffineTransform scale API`

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not speaking well, but I want to say that I would like 2 different animations (the circle) and the icon inside.